# What is a word or shorter phrase for "got the wind knocked out of me"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, american-english, synonyms

In American English, I'm wondering if there is a shorter way to express this (literal) experience. The phrase seems so wordy to me and it's hard to believe that there isn't something more concise. As a native speaker, I have never heard of anything else and alternatives I've thought of such as "winded" or "lost my breath" have different connotations. I'm interested in any alternatives including neologisms and loan words.

Comment: It depends on whether you mean it literally or figuratively. Figuratively, it can be a thousand and one things, surely.

Comment: @Lambie, I mean literally. I just added that to the body of the question.

Comment: I would have used 'winded' but you don't like that. Since it is commonplace in games such as rugby, maybe you could find something suitable in related jargon?

Comment: @LeeLeon, I think "winded" is more of a British English term. To me, "winded" is not a sudden thing. I am winded after running, not after getting hit.

Comment: "My diaphragm was paralyzed after being forcefully struck in the stomach, leaving me temporarily unable to breath." Hahaha! I think we might be stuck with "I got the wind knocked out of me."

Comment: I don't think winded is particularly British at all. But, it is not the same as having the wind knocked out of you. Believe me, when this happens to you, it's worth using this phrase. :)

Comment: I would (UK English) use winded for the result of a punch or a tackle (rugby)  - "he has been winded by his opponent" etc.

Comment: Would [_suffocated_](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/suffocate) work for you?

Comment: How could there ever be a "word" for such a phrase, please?

Why would anyone - including you - seek a shorter phrase?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, as you can see in the other comments, some people use the word "winded". "I was winded" is equivalent in meaning to "I got the wind knowcked out of me". So clearly there could be a "word" for a such a phrase. I seek a shorter phrase because I find the phrase to be long and unwieldy.

Answer (score 6):

It's hardly conversational, but the one-word term is ***phrenospasm***, according to the [Free Medical Dictionary](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/phrenospasm) available online.  A blow to the chest can cause the diaphragm to go into spasm, making it difficult to draw a breath.

Chances are that unless you're speaking or writing to a medical professional, you're better off with "*having the wind knocked out*."

Comment: I married an ANP...over time one soaks up this stuff.

Comment: Hmm, you can also have the wind knocked out of you when you get a punch in the stomach. Or when hit by something in the chest really hard (e.g. John Miller in Saving Private Ryan where he takes a bullet, although it is unclear if this is just a euphemism used by Captain Miller).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - Medically speaking, I'm told it's also related to hiccups.

Comment: Another medical term, for the phenomenon is solar-plexus syndrome. it doesn't lend itself to acting as a verb, but it brings the term solar plexus to the arena. Could you say "The projectile struck me just below my ribs. Its mass and velocity were stopped by my solar plexus. Time took a time-out; I found I couldn't breathe. I couldn't even try to breathe."

Answer (score 0):

I have one small suggestion.  It has nothing to do with wind being knocked out of one.  But they might do for this kind of unpleasant feeling of sudden shock.

I felt  pole-axed.

The Collins dictionary explains:-

“If someone is pole-axed, they are so surprised or shocked that they do not know what to say or do.
[mainly British, informal]
Sitting pole-axed on the sofa, Mahoney stared in astonishment at the spectacle before him.”

Comment: That’s clearly only a viable option for the metaphorical sense, though. This question is asking about the literal sense of having trouble breathing after someone punches you in the stomach.

Comment: Well, yes.  I took Robert to be looking for a metaphorical way to express the idea.  In fact, of course, the use of the word ‘winded’ (which I think could be used in this context) is itself to some extent metaphorical.  S a matter of a fact, I think there is nothing wrong with the expression he started out with.  Except on Twitter, one word is not always best.