# Is there a word for being completely drained of breath?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was singing and at the end of a long phrase I felt like I had expelled every last drop of breath in my body. Is there a word for that?

Example sentence:

> Wow, that phrase completely _____ me.

I was thinking along the lines of *eviscerate* but that feels too far off.

---

I am not expecting a common expression, in fact, if a word comes up, I am half expecting it to be archaic.

Comment: _OED_ lists the obsolete verb "abreathe" for this sense but I can't post as an answer as it is not used today. (_debreathe_ could work also). _Outbreathe_ is not obsolete or archaic and one of the senses possibly matches ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/outbreathe)), although possibly very uncommon. (never heard in this sense and couldn't find an example)

Comment: @ermanen, I wasn't aware of that limitation on answers

Comment: You are *"out of puff"* (in colloqiual British English)

Comment: @ermanen You can -totally- post that as an answer... just make sure to be explicit about it not being used nowadays.

Comment: Out of breath = Breathless.

Comment: Consider dropping the "single word" request?  Then suddenly there are plenty of good ideas already provided.  (My favorite: "emptied me of breath.")

Comment: "Wow, that phrase left me winded"

Comment: How about "deflated"?

Comment: the connected link (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/421150/what-is-a-word-or-shorter-phrase-for-got-the-wind-knocked-out-of-me) is not the same, because it is talking about being 2having the wind knocked out of you", and doesn't actually have an accepted answer, in fact it only has 1 poor answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the most obvious word would be **deflated**

> having been emptied of air or gas.

However, deflated has very common figurative usage which is

> having suddenly lost confidence or optimism.

so it could be confusing, depending on if the listener chose the literal or figurative use of the word.

Answer (score 24):

The typical verb to use would be *winded*:

> to make it difficult or temporarily impossible for someone to breathe, usually by hitting them in the stomach — [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/wind)

(See also the [adjective *winded*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/winded).)

Comment: I was able to breath the next action was a huge intake of breath.

Comment: @WendyG You should add that qualification to your question. I thought this was the best answer before I read your comment. I think the longer way of describing it is that 'you sang one note for so long that you emptied your lungs' and you're looking for a single verb for that. You're not short of breath or out of breath from physical exertion, you simply breathed out once until there was nothing to breath out, Add that kind of clarification to your question.

Comment: The singer wasn't hit in the stomach, and was able to take another breath. Someone becomes winded, not because they exhaled a complete lungful of air, but because of oxygen deprivation in the blood. This isn't even close and I would downvote, expect I posted an answer, so I won't.

Comment: When I sang in a children's choir, this is the term that we used for this phenomenon. One would also become "winded" after sprinting, say, or another strenuous form of exercise. I've never heard the "hitting" qualification, to be honest ... maybe some regional usage quirks.

Comment: I've heard being out of breath from something violent expressed as "having the wind knocked out". Simply "winded" is for exercise -- "I'm winded after all of those stairs".

Comment: When I was a kid, I only ever heard "winded" in the context of a blow - for instance, falling, landing on your back and being completely unable to breathe for a while. Some kind of diaphragm malfunction? But more recently it just seeems to mean "extremely out of breath to the point of not being able to talk even a little bit".

Comment: Have to agree with Cambridge, Laurel and Steve here. *To me*, winded means to have the air forced out of you by physical impact (though I'm sure metaphors apply). It probably isn't the word you're looking for.

Comment: Googling "winded" gives many examples, including dictionary definitions, or it being from exercise.

Comment: The idiomatic way to say this would be: "That phrase left me completely winded".

Comment: "Winded" definitely doesn't only apply to being punched in the stomach. If someone told me they were winded I would immediately think they had been running or some other form of exercise. Being punched in the stomach would be the absolute last thing that would come to mind. The top dictionary results also include definitions that mention physical exertion. However, the implication of "winded" is that you are breathing heavily for some period after and not just that you ran out of air and needed to take a quick breath, so I'm not sure it's exactly correct here.

Comment: @Herohtar Agreed.  The phrase I would use for the given definition would be 'knocked the wind out of'  or 'got the wind knocked out of them'.  'Winded' refers to being out of breath from exertion in my mind.

Comment: The definition supplied is not American English. *Winded* means "out of breath" — not "unable to breathe," and definitely not as a result of a blow.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest

> That long phrase completely spent my breath.

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/spend)

> **spend**
> <sub>VERB</sub>
>
> **1.1** Use or give out the whole of; exhaust.

Comment: 14 results for "spent my breath" in an adjusted Google search, and two of these for termination of life, means that this is not an idiomatic expression. This can be no more than writing advice (and I'd say working 'drained' in somehow would be better). And OP asks for a single word, correctly supplying an example sentence.

Comment: @Edwin It doesn't fit my sentence but it reminds me of "that phrase totally spent me" which i do like (although it makes me think of victorian erotica)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am unsure whether there *is* an idiomatic expression for a singer who used an entire lungful of air. I didn't think 'winded' was correct, because a singer (or wind instrument player) doesn't get winded in the same way as an athlete. They just use a whole lungful and then draw another breath, rather than needing a recovery period.

Comment: I think that ballpark answers miss the point of the site.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth and another answer misses the point of the question, which is 'worse', assuming the point of this site is to help the people who ask questions.

Comment: No; that's a secondary objective (still very important, where possible without allowing off-topic questions). Writing advice/suggestions that might just please OP if not really helping anyone else belong/s elsewhere.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth so this is a self-serving site then?

Comment: The issue is they don't want a word to fill in "_____ of breath". They want a single word (or phrase if no single word) that means "drained of breath" all by itself.  "Spent" isn't that word -- "I"m spent" means very tired, not breathless.

Comment: @OwenReynolds good point it does doesn't it

Comment: @OwenReynolds Sometimes a person asks a question, but what they really need is something else. It's OK to give a phrase when a single word just won't do. It could be that the OP has set it up improperly (eg they ask for an adjective but the intention is managed best by a verb). Just be explicit though.

Comment: " ... so this is a self-serving site then?" No, it's meant to be a reliable, focused resource addressing English language issues of a non-basic nature, without trespassing into say writing advice, jargon, analysis of literature .... If a question is likely to be of little use to more than OP, it's almost certainly off-topic. And I'd have knocked off a style mark at A-Level in my teaching days for 'That long phrase completely spent my breath', sounding so unnatural.

Answer (score 3):

That phrase completely **emptied** you.

You would be relying on context to suggest that your lungs were emptied of breath, but the verb **empty** can apply to lungs as it applies to other literal and figurative containers ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/empty), esp. def. 1a and 1c):

> transitive verb
>
> 1a : to make empty : remove the contents of empty a purse
> [...]
>
> c : to discharge (itself) of contents

For instance:

> The shot [was] close enough to my spine that it **emptied me** of breath. (Hilleman, A. (2017). *World, Chase Me Down*. [Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/World_Chase_Me_Down/DkkaDAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22emptied+me%22+breath&pg=PT150&printsec=frontcover))

> My breath poured out of me in a long, silent, heaving sob. It **emptied me** so completely that I knew my recovering intake of breath would be enough to wake the boys. (Williford, T.L. (2019). *Just. You. Wait.*. [Google Books](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Just_You_Wait/fod6DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22emptied+me%22+breath&pg=PA86&printsec=frontcover).)

Comment: *Drained* also works. Breathless should be used in a rewrite.

Comment: The quotes seem to argue against "emptied" by itself -- they both add "of breath", since "emptied" by itself isn't clear. Drained is the same way -- it someone says they're emptied or drained, w/o specifying of what, I think we'd assume emotionally, or stamina-wise.

Comment: Well, yes. *Emptied* has to be used in a context where it's clear breathing is involved, whether or not "breath" is mentioned. Singing a phrase would qualify as that context.

Answer (score 3):

"I ran out of air."  This avoids the connotations of being tired or having used up all one's blood oxygen.

Comment: There's an easy to miss tag: single-word-request. They would like one word that all by itself means "completely drained of breath". It sounds silly, but there are many cases where there's 1 perfect word, like "slush" for "wet partially melted snow".

Comment: I would use breath rather than air, but I agree with this answer that there isn't a single word to replace the concept. I offer this [article](https://www.spencerwelch.com/sing-without-losing-breath/) in supporting evidence which is about how to manage the phenomena as a singer and never supplies a single word option.

Answer (score 3):

> Wow, that phrase completely expended me

Is fine and normal enough, although I think "winded" is the most obvious especially without context.

> **expend**
> (verb) spend or use up (a resource such as money or energy): *the energy expended in sport could be directed into other areas.*

Oxford Dictionary of English

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is non-medical term in common usage for this. The proper word is "hypoxiated", unless you have literally expelled every single last molecule of oxygen, in which case you have become "anoxiated".

The closest commonly-used word would be "asphyxiated", although technically this is the term for the condition of your tissues and secondary respiratory processes after after they have been depleted of oxygen, not the word for the reduction of oxygen levels itself.

Comment: This sound like it could come from other causes than a complete relaxation of the diaphragm on one breath (eg lack of oxygen in the air that is breathed in, collapsed lung etc). The OP is describing when they've taken in one breath, and expelled it all, as much as they can in one action.